# Consume my REST API without getting token authenticated for my web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I have a created a simple WCF REST service, and implemented token-based security. Only users belonging  to a certain role can access my WCF REST service. The token is sent via Request-Header and is parsed  in the BaseService.cs method of my REST project. Each user, in order to access the REST API, has to  create his/her own token (if their role has the permission to access my REST API).

Since I have wrapped a considerable amount business logic in this REST WCF project, I would like to  leverage this REST API in my ASP.NET web project too. But my ASP.NET project has no "token", so how  can it consume the REST service? If I create a "special token" to indentify that its my Web  application consuming the REST Service and by-pass the user token authentication system, then  application users might hack and copy that token and consume the REST API.

Basically I want to know if its possible for my web application to consume my REST API without getting  token authenticated, like using some internal Visual Studio reference or something else?

I know I can be on a completely different track here as I am a newbie in WCF. If you can share your thoughts here, it would help me go in the right direction.

Comment: A code example would be useful. It's hard to imagine the token-based security you are envisioning. How do you get a token if you aren't authenticated?

Comment: Agree with neotapir, more details and code are needed. Hard to imagine situation and for me is not clear why approach with special token wouldn't work. If this approach is correctly implemented, end-users of asp.net site will never know anything about this token